# Why can't I turn on HDR on my Nikon DSLR?

Tags: hdr, nikon-d5500

There is something not allowing me to turn the HDR feature on, but I don’t know what it is.

Answer (score 3):

The most common reason would be that HDR cannot be used in Raw mode.  Also I think Bulb shutter and Interval timer might be issues for HDR too